# Aligning a Multiline Equation and Implication

Tags: align, split

I’m trying to align the first two equals signs with one another while aligning the implication symbol with the first limit; I tried to do this with the following code but the text was distorted as pictured. How can I fix this?

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \forall j\in\left\{1,...,n\right\}\
    &\lim\limits_{\textit{t}\to0^+}
    \frac{
        \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+\textit{t}\mathbf{e}_j)
        -\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})
        -\textit{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(\textit{t}\mathbf{e}_j)
        }
        {
        \textit{t}
        }
    &&=\lim\limits_{\textit{t}\to0^+}
    \frac{
        \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+\textit{t}\mathbf{e}_j)
        -\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})
        }
        {
        \textit{t}
        }
    -\textit{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{e}_j) \\
    &&=0 \\
    &\Rightarrow
    \forall j\in\left\{1,...,n\right\}\
    \lim\limits_{\textit{t}\to0^+}
    \frac{
        \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+\textit{t}\mathbf{e}_j)
        -\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})
        }
        {
        \textit{t}
        }
    =\textit{D}\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{e}_j)
\end{alignat*}
```

[image: An implication about Jacobians. However, the text is distorted.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please start by replacing all 24 instances of `\textbf` with `\mathbf`.

Comment: @Mico Done; thank you for the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or maybe something like this?

[image]

Don't be shy about using words and -- gasp -- entire half-sentences to help make your point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

For all $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, we have
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    &\lim_{t\to0^+}
     \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{e}_j)
          -\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})
         -D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(t\mathbf{e}_j)}{t}
    &&=\lim_{t\to0^+}
     \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{e}_j)
          -\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})}{t}
         -D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{e}_j)\\
    &&&= 0 \,.
\end{alignat*}
Thus, for all $j\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, we have shown that
\[
    \lim_{t\to0^+}
    \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{e}_j)
         -\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})}{t}
    = D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{e}_j)\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about removing all redundant `\limits`?

Comment: @egreg - Definitely a good idea. :-)

Comment: @Mico My original goal was nearly what your first version was, just with the implication aligned with the first limit. (I have a break before the second equals sign because of the size of my paper.) This version is definitely more immediately legible, though.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, I didn’t know they were redundant.

Comment: @Experimental-Mathematics - Speakng for myself, I don't think that much, if anything, is gained by aligning the `\lim` terms vertically.

Answer (score 2):

I hope to understand your question. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \begin{split}
    &\forall j\in\{1,\ldots,n\} \\
    &\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{e}_j) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}) - D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(t\mathbf{e}_j)}{t}  = \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{e}_j) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})}{t} - D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{e}_j)=0
   \end{split} \\
    \Rightarrow &\forall j\in\{1,\ldots,n\} \\
    \begin{split}
    &\lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a}+t\mathbf{e}_j) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})}{t} = D\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{a})(\mathbf{e}_j)
    \end{split}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Close, but I want the statement to be more horizontal — I’m trying to get breaks only before the second equals sign and before the implication; then, get the implication to line up with the first limit.

Comment: @Experimental-Mathematics I have done an edit.